# play mp4 when it recorded in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

i try to recored a video on opencv/python

and in the same time to play it(with some delay)
for example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
```

and after it starts recording run the second file:
(the end goal is to publish it on web server)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("output.mp4")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

my problem is when I try to play the file - i get an error "file in use"

in theory, i know it possible - when i download a torrent i can start watching the video before it finishes downloading.

thanks.

if i try it with xvid codec the second file cut the recording when it start playing

Comment: no.
(i add some infomation in the post.)